# How to access name in NameError?

Tags: python, nameerror

I would like to catch a NameError and then access the name and use it to provide a better message. How do I access the name that is causing the error without parsing the error message?

```
try:
    love_bug = herbie
except NameError as err:
    name = get_name(err)
    print(name, 'unknown.')
```

In other words, how do I implement get_name() in the above code?

Comment: Hint: regex pattern match. Please dont expect us to code for you. If you are stuck specifically with an issue in your code, your chances of getting a more qualified resopnse is much higher.

Comment: Can you provide the output you are expecting? Because if you just print `err` you get `name 'herbie' is not defined`. What do you want beyond that? That's pretty clear as is.

Comment: I am not happy using the normal message and want to create my own. Perhaps I want to translate it to a different language, or make it more specific to the situation. How do I access just the offending name. I have come up with: `name = str(err).split("'")[1]`, but I cannot help but feeling that there must be a better way.

Comment: If you think there is a better/easier way, inspect the exception object and see if there actually is extra information you can use. If not, then you will have to deal with what you just figured out. Your alternative option is to come up with your own custom exception class that inherits from NameError, raise that, do your "magic" in there, and work accordingly to craft your own exception messaging that you want to propagate.

Comment: Yeah, did that. Found nothing. I'm a bit surprised. Other exceptions such as OSError give you access to the components of the message.

Comment: Oh, and I have no control over how the exception is raised initially. I am stuck with NameError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must yank the name from `NameError.args[0]`:

```
>>> try:
...     print(foo)
... except NameError as e:
...     print(re.search("'(?P<name>.+?)'", e.args[0]).group('name'))
...
foo
```

Comment: Well this is not what I was looking for as it is parsing the message, which is fragile and will likely break if Guido changes the way NameErrors are formatted. However, I am accepting it as it made it clear to me that there is no hope of getting what I want. Printing e.args shows that the bare name is never passed into the exception, so there is no way I could retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_name(err):
    last = err.find("' ")
    return err[6:last]
try:
    love_bug= heribie
except NameError  as err:
    print(get_name(err.args[0]), "unknown")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question, you can create you're own error, like this:

```
class ValidateName(NameError):
    def __init__(self, name):
        # Call the base class constructor with the parameters it needs
        super().__init__(self, "unknown name " + name) #or whatever you need to add

try:
  love_bug = "herbie"
  raise ValidateName(love_bug) #there is no point in raising the exception manually here, I did this only to show how the message is shown,obliviously somewhere in your code the exception is raised 
except ValidateName as err:
  print(err)
```

> (ValidateName(...), 'unknown name herbie')

Comment: @PauloScardine Ah no no, there is no point at all, just do it to show the error message because the OP in the code didn't show the part when the error may be thrown